# Continuous input, how to undo the last movements

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard

Samsung's continuous input method works nicely in many situations.

However, when writing rather long words as they occur in German, the input method sometimes gives up and the entire word swished so far is gone.

What is the best method to handle this situation? Is there a way to retain at least part of the word?